# CNTK C# Library 2.0beta11 (CNTK.CPUOnly): sequence of sparse vectors

Tags: c#, cntk

Perhaps I'm missing something in the documentation, but how can I create an input which is a sequence of sparse vectors in the new CNTK.CPUOnly NuGet package in C#? (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Evaluation-Overview)

All I see in the available API is support for sequence of dense vectors.

I was able to do it using the EvalDLL API (from the Microsoft.Research.CNTK.CpuEval-mkl NuGet package), but I'm having some thread-safety issues, which prompted me to try out the newer API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the C# API supports to create one-hot vector for sequence and/or batch. For example, to create a sequence using:

```
public static Value CreateSequence<T>(uint dimension, List<uint> sequence, bool seqStartFlag, DeviceDescriptor device, bool readOnly = false)
```

or create a batch of sequence:

```
public static Value CreateBatchOfSequences<T>(uint dimension, List<List<uint>> batchOfSequences, List<bool> seqStartFlags, DeviceDescriptor device, bool readOnly = false
```

The API description is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Managed-API), and the examples are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Examples/Evaluation/CNTKLibraryEvalExamples.sln). 
Support for general sparse format will be added in the next few weeks.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. One-hot won't work in my case -- I'm looking forward to the support for sequences of general sparse vectors!

Comment: Hi, is there any new ETA/roadmap on sparse batch variable creation support?